# How do you use a wildcard or regex with phpMyAdmin in order to ignore a portion of a search term?

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

For example, I'm attempting to search a Wordpress database for all occurrences of a particular URL that has a link target set to _blank. Because the URL can vary beyond the base domain, I'm trying to determine how to properly use the wildcard option in phpMyAdmin in order to ignore the non base portion of the domain name in my search. As an example, suppose I have the following lines contained within the database:

`<a href="http://somelink.com/this-is-a-red-car/" target="_blank">`
`<a href="http://somelink.com/this-is-a-blue-coat/" target="_blank">`
`<a href="http://somelink.com/this-is-a-purple-box/">`
`<a href="http://somelink.com/this-is-a-green-house/" target="_blank">`

`<a href="http://somelink.com/this-is-a-yellow-lemon">`

Keeping in mind that the database is filled with thousands of unique URL's with a mixture of different link targets, What would be an effective way to use phpMyAdmin's Search feature using a wildcard or regex to return results that include somelink.com/any-possible-post-title/ as well as target="_blank" ?

I tried entering the following search term, but it returned many irrelevant results, including URL's besides the one I searched for:

`<a href="http://somelink.com/%/" target="_blank" ?>`

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong, and what the proper way to go about this would be? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<a href="http:\/\/somelink.com\/[a-zA-z-0-9]*\/"\s+target="_blank">
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up tweaking your answer a bit since my Wordpress database entries included \ before and after "_blank - so I used the following:



`http:\/\/somelink.com\/[a-zA-z-0-9]*\"\s+target=\\"_blank\\"`


P.S. In instances where there was a trailing slash on a URL, I used the following regex:



`http:\/\/somelink.com\/[a-zA-z-0-9\/]*\"\s+target=\\"_blank\\"`